# Creating a dictionary from two lists in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a JSON data as below.

```
input_list = [["Richard",[],{"children":"yes","divorced":"no","occupation":"analyst"}],
["Mary",["testing"],{"children":"no","divorced":"yes","occupation":"QA analyst","location":"Seattle"}]]
```

I have another list where I have the prospective keys present

```
list_keys = ['name', 'current_project', 'details']
```

I am trying to create a dic using both to make the data usable for metrics

I have summarized the both the list for the question but it goes on forever, there are multiple elements in the list. input_list is a nested list which has 500k+ elements and each list element have 70+ elements of their own (expect the details one)
list_keys also have 70+ elements in it.

I was trying to create a dict using zip but that its not helping given the size of data, also with zip I am not able to exclude the "details" element from

I am expecting output something like this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Richard",
    "current_project": "",
    "children": "yes",
    "divorced": "no",
    "occupation": "analyst"
    },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "current_project" :"testing",
    "children": "no",
    "divorced": "yes",
    "occupation": "QA analyst",
    "location": "Seattle"
    }
]
```

I have tried this so far

```
>>> for line in input_list:
...     zipbObj = zip(list_keys, line)
...     dictOfWords = dict(zipbObj)
...
>>> print dictOfWords
{'current_project': ['testing'], 'name': 'Mary', 'details': {'location': 'Seattle', 'children': 'no', 'divorced': 'yes', 'occupation': 'QA analyst'}}
```

but with this I am unable to to get rid of nested dict key "details". so looking for help with that

Comment: How does your existing code look like? If it is working but you are looking into improving it, Code Review stack exchange may be a better place to ask.

Comment: @selcuk updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you wanted was a list of dictionaries, here is something i coded up in the terminal and copied in here. Hope it helps.

```
>>> list_of_dicts = []
>>> for item in input_list:
...     dict = {}
...     for i in range(0, len(item)-2, 3):
...             dict[list_keys[0]] = item[i]
...             dict[list_keys[1]] = item[i+1]
...             dict.update(item[i+2])
...     list_of_dicts.append(dict)
...
>>> list_of_dicts
[{'name': 'Richard', 'current_project': [], 'children': 'yes', 'divorced': 'no', 'occupation': 'analyst'
}, {'name': 'Mary', 'current_project': ['testing'], 'children': 'no', 'divorced': 'yes', 'occupation': '
QA analyst', 'location': 'Seattle'}]
```

I will mention it is not the ideal method of doing this since it relies on perfectly ordered items in the input_list.

Comment: Hi @Cavenfish, Thanks for checking on this. This code is working fine but I have multiple elements close to 75, adding the index  for each of them will make the code complex.

Comment: Hey @yahoo_it, you can still use this style of code even with the large element size in the list_keys (so long as the order of the input_list is correct). Just nest another loop in the like this: `for key in list_keys:` then the insertion would be `dict[key] = item[i]` from within the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
people = input_list = [["Richard",[],{"children":"yes","divorced":"no","occupation":"analyst"}],
["Mary",["testing"],{"children":"no","divorced":"yes","occupation":"QA analyst","location":"Seattle"}]]
list_keys = ['name', 'current_project', 'details']
listout = []
for person in people:
    dict_p = {}
    for key in list_keys:
        if not key == 'details':
            dict_p[key] = person[list_keys.index(key)]
        else:
            subdict = person[list_keys.index(key)]
            for subkey in subdict.keys():
                dict_p[subkey] = subdict[subkey]

    listout.append(dict_p)
listout
```

The issue with using zip is that you have that additional dictionary in the `people` list.  This will get the following output, and should work through a larger list of individuals:

```
[{'name': 'Richard',
  'current_project': [],
  'children': 'yes',
  'divorced': 'no',
  'occupation': 'analyst'},
 {'name': 'Mary',
  'current_project': ['testing'],
  'children': 'no',
  'divorced': 'yes',
  'occupation': 'QA analyst',
  'location': 'Seattle'}]
```

Comment: This worked fine in the terminal but when I trying to run the script with the data its throwing error
```
    for subkey in subdict.keys():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

```

Answer (score 0):

This script will go through every item of `input_list` and creates new list where there aren't any list or dictionaries:

```
input_list = [
    ["Richard",[],{"children":"yes","divorced":"no","occupation":"analyst"}],
    ["Mary",["testing"],{"children":"no","divorced":"yes","occupation":"QA analyst","location":"Seattle"}]
]

list_keys = ['name', 'current_project', 'details']

out = []
for item in input_list:
    d = {}
    out.append(d)
    for value, keyname in zip(item, list_keys):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d.update(**value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            if value:
                d[keyname] = value[0]
            else:
                d[keyname] = ''
        else:
            d[keyname] = value

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'children': 'yes',
  'current_project': '',
  'divorced': 'no',
  'name': 'Richard',
  'occupation': 'analyst'},
 {'children': 'no',
  'current_project': 'testing',
  'divorced': 'yes',
  'location': 'Seattle',
  'name': 'Mary',
  'occupation': 'QA analyst'}]
```